# How to calculate number of paychecks in a semi-monthly basis?

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet

I know I can easily count it using a calendar, still I wonder, how would a formula tell me the answer if usually people are paid by the 5th and 20th of the month.

Example:
Date of hire: 02/06/19
Last pay day:10/21/19
How many paychecks accumulated? What is the formula in Excel?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please elaborate. Give a simple but precise use case. i.e. it's not really clear what your environment is and what your data looks like. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What have you tried? Where did that fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SUMPRODUCT to iterate the days from start to end.  Use DAY() to return the day of the month of those dates and if it equals 5 or 20 then count it:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((DAY(ROW(INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,A1):INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,A2)))=5)+(DAY(ROW(INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,A1):INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,A2)))=20))
```

[image]

Comment: It works perfectly!! Thank you!!!

Comment: Hello, what if I try to add a range of days, instead of a singular day of 5 and 20; for example: replace the "5" for "1 to 14", and replace the "20" for "15 to 31". How should the formula be modified?

Comment: That is a new question.